# communication between 2 programs in python

Tags: python, sockets, inter-process-communicat

I have 2 programs that are both in python, one is 3rd Party and already been made. I want to run one in the foreground and one in the background. I want to set up a communication between the 2 programs, so I can tell the one in the foreground to do something, and it then tell the other program to do something. Such as on the foreground program I press a button, which then tell the other program to do something.
What is the best way to do bout this?

I know I have asked a question about this before, but I feel that people might have found that too specific, so I have written a more simplified question.

Comment: [have you read this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920858/interprocess-communication-in-python?rq=1)

Comment: You don't need to make two programs. Just create a thread in the main program that will do the job.

Comment: look my answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213235/communication-between-two-python-scripts/16213366#16213366

Comment: look my answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213235/communication-between-two-python-scripts/16213366#16213366

Comment: in [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3922174/15842840) various solutions are proposed, including sockets, IPC, Posix based messages, DBUS , Multi Processing module etc .. At least one of them should be found useful for such circumstances ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my experience, rpyc is by far the simplest, most elegant, and most flexible way to go about it. http://rpyc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/