# Execute a script python in a terminal and call one of their functions from another terminal

Tags: python

I'm beginner in python and I've a question. I need to execute a script in a terminal in a loop and to call one of their functions from another one terminal i.e. my first script will be run all the time in a terminal 1 and I need to call a function from this script in execution by another one terminal 2. How I can do it ?

Thanks !

Comment: so you want to have two different scripts or only one?

Comment: have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213235/communication-between-two-python-scripts

Comment: @finnmglas two differents scripts. Basically I need to send a parameter to the function of the first script and receive a result in another terminal (terminal of second script).