# Communication between two running scripts

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to share a variable between two already running scripts. Or even spit string from one script to another.

**script_1.py:**

```
sensor_status = "Nobody"
while 1:
    sensor_status = arduino.get_sensor_status()
    sleep(5)
```

**script_2.py:**

```
sensor_status = # realtime value from script_1
while 1:
    if sensor_status == "Nobody":
        pass
    else:
        alarm()
```

Comment: I think `multithreading` might work here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Communication between two python scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213235/communication-between-two-python-scripts)

Comment: You should add a `sleep()` to script 2 or it will run at 100% CPU.

Comment: @Wizix Not really. The thing is, its more complex than that. It can be ran multiple times for different purposes. I can create a session file with an extension of .txt where both can access it but neither this or setting ports manual seems automated. Just hoping something quicker.

Comment: @Kepler186 Why dont't you call `script_1` from `script_2` by importing it in `script_2`?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma I mean I could've also removed script_2 and proceed to execute alarm() whenever the condition is not satisfied. But that's not the idea, and again, the script is more complex than that, what I want is a way to communicate between two already running scripts. Is it possible?

Comment: Then can you use, as @Sociopath suggested, the ` multithreading` module and use a pipe or a queue ?

Comment: @Wizix Hmm. I shall look it up. But if you have any useful links, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Is the communication one-way or two-way?  What kind of computer are the scripts running on?  You could use the multiprocessing library.  The docs have producer/consumer examples.  You could also use something like MQTT.

Comment: Take a look at this article: [Introduction to Multiprocessing in Python](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-multiprocessing-in-python--cms-30281)

Comment: @RootTwo / Wizix
Beautiful. Multiprocessing's pipes seems the perfect solution. Thanks.